# How is this motor switch wired?

Tags: capacitor, motor, wiring

I've just purchased this Brooks Crompton 4 pole 3/4 HP single phase motor, that came off a Record CL3 lathe. The plate is too worn out to see any info, so I can't find a wiring diagram.

I want to use it with a pillar drill I have, so I want to bypass the NVR switch on the motor to use the switch on the drill instead.

The 'brighter' blue and brown wires are the live and neutral from the mains, and only have continuity when the switch is closed. With the switch open, there is continuity between all the dull wires, which go to the motor and capacitor. There is no continuity between the black leads and any others, unless the switch is closed, and then I can sometimes get continuity. Does this has something to do with the capacitor?

Any advice is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the wiring diagram courtesy [*BAPTIST.NL*](https://baptist.nl/uploads/bijlagen/record-cl3cl4-manual.pdf).

Please refer page # 37.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking, but there's a few different CL3 lathes and it's not possible to tell which one; they all have slightly different wiring, so sadly I can't just go off the diagram.#

Comment: Anytime, Noah! I'm sorry the schematic did not help.